# Html lists side by side - whats the correct way?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists

I have 3 unordered lists that sit side by side, like this:

```
<ul><li>list 1</li></ul> <ul><li>list 2</li></ul> <ul><li>list 3</li></ul>
```

Are they considered a list of lists, and therefore be within another ul/li tag, or is their containing Div adequate?

Comment: It is impossible to say what the correct semantics to describe a set of data are when that data has been replaced by placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to decide whether they're a list of lists, or just three distinct lists that happen to be laid out side by side (that's where CSS comes in).

If they're not a list of lists, then a containing `div` is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

You use this style code for ul and li

```
ul{
  float:right;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:500px;
  clear:both;
}
```

and use for li

```
ul li{
  float:right;
  width:100%;
}
```